# ¿Como puedo hacer una paginación que cuando llegue al número 10 muestre después del 11 al 20?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

estoy intentando hacer una páginación para un slider y lo que quería hacer era que cuando tu hicieras click en el 10 y apareciera el 11 desapareciera la primera lista del 1 al 10 y mostrara la del 11 al 20, intente poner todas las clases en css con display: none; en todos los elementos del 1 al 23 a la variable le agregue un

```javascript
list1 = document.getElementByClassName("slider-none__3__1");
if (n = 1 && posicion == 10) {
    lista2[posicion].style.display = ' inline-block';
}
```

obviamente se que el codigo esta muy mal hecho por que no funciona
entonces antes también había intentado hacer una especie de active pero me confundí y ya no entendí que había salido mal, y después intente con

```js
let indice1 = 1;
     muestrario1( indice1 );
        
function avanzarFoto1(n1){
    muestrario1( indice1+=n1 );
}
    
function posicion1(n1){
    muestrario1( indice1=n1 );
}

setInterval(function tiempo1(){
          muestrario1( indice1+=1 )
},3000);

function muestrario1(n1){
     let ite1;
     let imagenes1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-img__1');
     let controlNavImgs1 = document.getElementsByClassName('li-control-nav__1');
 
     if(n1 > imagenes1.length ){
         indice1 = 1;
     }
     if(n1 < 1){
         indice1 = imagenes1.length;
     }
     for(ite1 = 0; ite1 < imagenes1.length ; ite1++){
         imagenes1[ite1].style.display = 'none';
     }
     for(ite1 = 0; ite1 < controlNavImgs1.length ; ite1++){
         controlNavImgs1[ite1].className = controlNavImgs1[ite1].className.replace(" active", "");
     }
 
     imagenes1 [indice1-1].style.display = ' block';
     controlNavImgs1[indice1 -1].className += ' active';
     
 }
```

```css
.flex-prev__1{ 
  background-color: rgb(48, 44, 44); 
  font-size: 40px; 
  color: #fff; 
  padding-left: 60%; 
  padding-right: 60%; 
  border-radius: 10px; 
  justify-content: center; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  border: 4px solid #a0a0a0; 
  position: relative; 
  right: 60px; 
  bottom: 60px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
} 

#lista-slider__1{ padding-left: 0; }

.img-items__1{ 
  display: inline-block; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  border: 10px double #3f0202 ; 
}

.slider-items__1{ display: flex;

}

.li-control-nav__1{ 
  display:inline-flex; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  position: relative; 
  bottom: 100px;
}

#box-slider__1{ 
  grid-column: 1/3; 
  grid-row:1/1; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 34%;
}

.wrapper{ 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto); 
  margin-left: 6%;

}
```

```javascript
function navcontroller(){
let tope= 10;

if (posicion < = 10 n < = tope)
}
```

La verdad de todo esto es que soy nueva y apenas estoy aprendiendo, ya sé html y css y sé que no es suficiente y estoy un tanto frustrada porque no puedo avanzar y aprender a hacerlo,

lo ideal sería una paginación que funcione con active con 10 elementos, agradecería mucho que me pudieras ayudar.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div  id="box-slider__1" >
      <ul id="lista-slider__1" >
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__1" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__1_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA1.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__2" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__2_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA2.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__3" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__3_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA3.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__4" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__4_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA4.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__5" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__5_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA5.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__6" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__6_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA6.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__7" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__7_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA7.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__8" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__8_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA8.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__9" ><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__9_1  "> <img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA9.png"  alt="" class=
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__10"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__10_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA10.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__11"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__11_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA11.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__12"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__12_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA12.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__13"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__13_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA13.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__14"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__14_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA14.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__15"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__15_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA15.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__16"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__16_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA16.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__17"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__17_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA17.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__18"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__18_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA18.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__19"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__19_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA19.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__20"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__20_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA20.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__21"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__21_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA21.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__22"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__22_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA22.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__23"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__23_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA23.png" alt="" class="
          <li class="slider-items__1" id="img-slider__24"><div class="slider-img__1 div-imgs__1" id="boxinbox-slider__24_1 "><img src="/sources/slider automatico 1/imgSA24.png" alt="" class="
```

```
      <ol class="flex-direction-nav">

        <li class="invisible"><a class="invisible__1" href="#"></a></li>

        <li class="flex-nav-prev__1"><button class="flex-prev__1" onclick="avanzarFoto1(-1)" >
          &#10094;</button></li>
        <li class="flex-nav-next__1"><button class="flex-next__1" onclick="avanzarFoto1(1)" >
          &#10095;</button></li>
        </ol>
```

```
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__1" onclick="posicion1(1)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">1</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__2" onclick="posicion1(2)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">2</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__3" onclick="posicion1(3)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">3</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__4" onclick="posicion1(4)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">4</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__5" onclick="posicion1(5)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">5</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__6" onclick="posicion1(6)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">6</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__7" onclick="posicion1(7)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">7</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__8" onclick="posicion1(8)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">8</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__9" onclick="posicion1(9)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">9</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__10" onclick="posicion1(10)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">10</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__11" onclick="posicion1(11)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">11</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__12" onclick="posicion1(12)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">12</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__13" onclick="posicion1(13)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">13</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__14" onclick="posicion1(14)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">14</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__15" onclick="posicion1(15)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">15</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__16" onclick="posicion1(16)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">16</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__17" onclick="posicion1(17)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">17</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__18" onclick="posicion1(18)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">18</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__19" onclick="posicion1(24)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">24</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__20" onclick="posicion1(19)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">19</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__21" onclick="posicion1(20)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">20</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__22" onclick="posicion1(21)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">21</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__23" onclick="posicion1(22)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">22</span>
            <span class="li-control-nav__1 slider-none__1" id="li-control-nav__24" onclick="posicion1(23)" class="posicion__1 .posicion__a1">23</span>
```

Comment: Hola mucho gusto, si créeme que todos sabemos lo frustrante que puede llegar a ser este tipo de problemas. Animo lo vas a lograr. Agrega por favor un ejemplo  de como tienes tu información pues parece ser más un error de como estas renderizando tu información. Con esto me refiero a si estas consumiendo datos de algún lado o simplemente intentas lograr una pagina estática

Comment: @DavElsanto Agradezco mucho tus buenos deseos c:, y creo que cuando uno empieza a programar acepta la clausula de tener problemas frustrantes y tener que resolverlos jajajaja, Creo que te refieres con una página estatica una página que no se mueve, el slider es para imagenes de una pasteleria, es con páginación (que bien se la podría quitar tengo que aprender) y la estoy alojando en mi propia maquina, el slider funciona bien, la paginación no la supe hacer ya que el código de arriba me confundia mucho en un momento te agrego la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de tu idea escribí esta función que logra el objetivo:

```
 function showPaginationControls(elements, activeElement){ 
  if(activeElement > 20)  showControlsBetween(21,24)  
  else if(activeElement > 10) showControlsBetween(11,20)
  else if (activeElement > 0) showControlsBetween(1,10)    
    
  function showControlsBetween(from, to){
    for(let i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
        if(i >= from - 1 && i < to ) elements[i].style.display = "inline-flex"
        else elements[i].style.display = "none"
     }
   }
 }
```

Básicamente la función itera en todos los controles y si encuentra que el índice del control se encuentre en uno de los rangos que se desea mostrar, asigna  la propiedad display del css a inline-flex y en caso contrario asigna none.

Se utiliza aqui en el js:

```
 ...
   function muestrario1(n1){
      let ite1;
      let imagenes1 = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-img__1');
      let controlNavImgs1 = document.getElementsByClassName('li-control-nav__1');
     
      if(n1 > imagenes1.length ){
          indice1 = 1;
      }
      if(n1 < 1){
          indice1 = imagenes1.length;
      }
    
    // AQUI LLAMO A LA FUNCIÓN
    
     showPaginationControls(controlNavImgs1, indice1)

        
//
     for(ite1 = 0; ite1 < imagenes1.length ; ite1++){
             imagenes1[ite1].style.display = 'none';
         }
         for(ite1 = 0; ite1 < controlNavImgs1.length ; ite1++){
             controlNavImgs1[ite1].className = controlNavImgs1[ite1].className.replace(" active", "");
         }
     
         imagenes1 [indice1-1].style.display = ' block';
         controlNavImgs1[indice1 -1].className += ' active';
         
     }
```

No es muy eficiente porque tiene que hacer 3 for loops porque son 3 rangos, pero lo puedes modificar y mejorar. Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias, está perfecto y muy entendible concuerdo contigo ya que al pensar cuando estaba haciendo el codigo también me di cuenta que a fuerza tenian que ser 3 loops y no sería eficiente, pero en base al problema es correcto y está bien ocupar los 3 loops, lo voy a probar pronto, ya que la escuela también me está ocupando muchisimo tiempo